# ¿Cómo añado los datos de un formulario a una base de datos con AJAX y PHP?

Tags: php, ajax

Buenas, estoy aprendiendo a usar AJAX pero de momento no lo entiendo del todo. 
Tengo un formulario del que cojo los datos y al dar al botón 'Add Question' quiero que lo añada a la base de datos sin cambiar de página. No pego el código de addQuestions.php porque este funciona correctamente.
Aquí va el **código**:

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(evento){
    $("#botoia1").click(function(evento){
     evento.preventDefault();
     $("#sQ").load('../PHP/showQuestionsAJAX.php');
    });
    
    $("#botoia2").click(function(evento){
         var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.open("POST", "../PHP/addQuestions.php", true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    });
  });
 </script>
  <div id='page-wrap'>
 <header class='main' id='h1'>
   <span class="right"><a href='layout.html'>LogOut</a> </span>
   <h2>Quiz: crazy questions</h2>
    </header>
 <nav class='main' id='n1' role='navigation'>
  <span><a href='handlingQuizes.php'>Galderak Kudeatu</a></span>
 </nav>
    <section class="main">
   <fieldset>
    <legend> Galdera Sortu </legend>
    <form id="galderenF" name="galderenF" method="post">
    
     <label for="posta"><strong>Posta (*):</strong></label>
     <input type="email" name="posta" id="posta" placeholder="Zein da zure posta?"  pattern="[a-zA-Z]{2,}[0-9]{3}@ikasle\.ehu\.(eus|es)"  required/><br>
     
     <label for="galdera"><strong>Galdera (*):</strong></label>
     <input type="text" name="galdera" minlength="10" id="galdera" placeholder="Zein da zure galdera?" required/><br>
     
     <label for="zuzena"><strong>Erantzun Zuzena (*):</strong></label>
     <input type="text" name="zuzena" id="erantzunZuzena" placeholder="Zein da zure erantzun zuzena?" required/><br>
     
     <label for="okerra1"><strong>Erantzun Okerra 1 (*):</strong></label>
     <input type="text" name="okerra1" id="erantzunOkerra" placeholder="Erantzun okerra 1" required/><br>
     
     <label for="okerra1"><strong>Erantzun Okerra 2 (*):</strong></label>
     <input type="text" name="okerra2" id="erantzunOkerra" placeholder="Erantzun okerra 2" required/><br>
     
     <label for="okerra1"><strong>Erantzun Okerra 3 (*):</strong></label>
     <input type="text" name="okerra3" id="erantzunOkerra" placeholder="Erantzun okerra 3" required/><br>
     
     <label for="zailtasuna"><strong>Zailtasuna<em>(1 - 5)</em> (*):</strong></label>
     <input type="number" min="1" max="5" name="zailtasuna" id="zailtasuna" placeholder="Zein da galderaren zailtasuna?" required/><br>
     
     <label for="arloa"><strong>Arloa(*):</strong></label>
     <input type="text" name="arloa" id="arloa" placeholder="Zein da galderaren arloa?" required/><br>
     <input class="botoia" type="reset" id="botoia" value="Reset" /> 
    </form>
    <input class="botoia" onClick = "showQuestions()" type="button" id="botoia1" value="Show Questions" />
    <input class="botoia" type="button" id="botoia2" value="Add Question" />
    <div id="aster" ><strong> * | Nahitaezko hutsuneak </strong></div><br><br>
   </fieldset>
    </section>
 <div id="sQ" align=center>
  
 </div>
 <footer class='main' id='f1'>
  <p><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quiz" target="_blank">What is a Quiz?</a></p>
  <a href='https://github.com'>Link GITHUB</a>
 </footer>
</div>
```

El div vacío se llena al darle al botón 'Show Questions' pero eso en mi duda no tiene relevancia. 
 He mirado en varias webs como w3school y aquí en stack overflow y no he conseguido nada. 
 El problema es que al hacer click en el botón 'Add Question' no hace nada. 
Saludos.

Este es el código **PHP** de **addQuestions.php**

```html
<?php
 $xmlstr="../XML/questions.xml";
 $local = 1;
 if($local == 0){
  $server ="localhost";
  $user = "root";
  $pass = "";
  $db = "quiz";
 }else{
  $server ="localhost";
  $user = "id3001514_t17";
  $pass = "12345";
  $db = "id3001514_quiz";
 }
 if (file_exists($xmlstr)) {
  $questions =  simplexml_load_file($xmlstr,null,true);
  $simpleXML = new SimpleXMLElement($questions->asXML());
  $question = $simpleXML->addChild('assessmentItem');
  $question->addChild('itemBody',$_POST['galdera']);
  $question->addAttribute('complexity',$_POST['zailtasuna']);
  $question->addAttribute('subject',$_POST['arloa']);
  $correct=$question->addChild('correctResponse');
  $correct->addChild('value',$_POST['zuzena']);
  $incorrect=$question->addChild('incorrectResponse');
  $incorrect->addChild('value',$_POST['okerra1']);
  $incorrect->addChild('value',$_POST['okerra2']);
  $incorrect->addChild('value',$_POST['okerra3']);
  
  $simpleXML->asXML($xmlstr); 
 } else {
  echo "Errorea, ezin izan da XML fitxategia ireki, path-a errebisatu edo fitxategia existitzen den";
 }
 $konektatu = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $db);
    
 $sql = "INSERT INTO questions VALUES('','$_POST[posta]', '$_POST[galdera]', '$_POST[zuzena]', '$_POST[okerra1]','$_POST[okerra2]','$_POST[okerra3]', '$_POST[zailtasuna]', '$_POST[arloa]')";

 $execute=mysqli_query($konektatu,$sql);
 if(!$execute){
  echo"Ezin izan dira datuak txertatu. ".mysqli_error($konektatu);
 }else{
  echo"Datuak txertatu egin dira";
  echo"<a href=../PHP/showQuestions.php> Ikusi Datuak </a><br>";
  echo'<a href=../PHP/showXMLQuestions.php>Ikusi Datuak (XML) </a>';
 }
 mysqli_close($konektatu);

?>
```

Comment: llegan tus datos al archivo php o donde te pierdes?

Comment: Perdon por no haber contestado antes, he andado ocupado. El problema es que los datos no se mandan a la base de datos y no sé como hacerlo. He probado el código de la única respuesta pero sigue dando error de momento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estás recogiendo los datos del formulario para pasarlos al servidor.

Tu script debería quedar así más o menos:

```
$(function() 
{ //Desde jQuery 3 document.ready es deprecated 
    $( '#botoia2' ).click(function(e) 
    {
        var frm = $("#galderenF");
        var data=frm.serialize(); //Recoge todo del form
        e.preventDefault(); 

        var request = $.ajax
            ({
                url: '../PHP/addQuestions.php',
                method: frm.prop('method'),
                data: data, //Manda los datos al servidor
                dataType: "html"  //puede ser también "json" depende de la respuesta
            });

            request.done(function( data ) 
            {
                //En este bloque manejas los datos recibidos del servidor
                console.log(data);
                alert("Todo bien");
                $('#resultado').html(data); //Muestras mensaje en un div

            });

            request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) 
            {
                alert( "Hubo un error: " + textStatus );
            });
    }       

});
```

En el `done` he puesto esto:

```
$('#resultado').html(data);
```

Si a tu documento HTML tú agregas este div:

```
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Se mostrará dentro de él lo que venga del servidor.

---

**P.D.**: Aunque sea otro tema, quiero señalar que las consultas que usas en tu PHP son vulnerables a la Inyección SQL. Es un riesgo de seguridad mayor, sobre el cual recomiendo que investigues en cuanto sea posible, para poder usar código seguro en el manejo de los datos.

Comment: Debes corregir `$( '#botoia2 )` por `$( '#botoia2')`.

Comment: Gracias @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez ya decía yo que se veía raro. Y había omitido una llave de cierre del click function `}`. Corregido.

Comment: Ahora sale aunque sea el alert pero da error todo el rato. ¿Eso puede ser el código PHP?

Comment: @MikelMolinuevo si el alert que te sale es el del error, puede ser el archivo mismo, o la dirección del archivo que no es correcta. Si pudieras revisar el error log de PHP te diría cuál es el problema exactamente. Si te sale el alert `Todo bien`, entonces el archivo responde. En ese bloque tienes que tratar la respuesta del servidor.

Comment: No sé a que te refieres con el error de log,  ¿dices el que sale por la consola?

Comment: @MikelMolinuevo primeramente dime cuál es el alert que sale, en el código hay dos tipos de alert, uno que dice `Todo bien` y otro que dice: `Hubo un error`. ¿Cuál es el que sale? El error log del que hablo es un archivo que PHP crea, en el que se escriben los errores del código. Es importante conocerlo, saber donde se encuentra y revisarlo. Te va a ahorrar horas identificando los errores.

Comment: Pone: Hubo un error: error

Comment: Si pone siempre eso es indicativo de un error en el archivo, o en la ruta del mismo: `../PHP/addQuestions.php`. Prueba primero a cambiar eso por una ruta absoluta del archivo (ruta completa) asegurándote de que es correcta. Si sigue dando el error, entonces significa que tu archivo tiene error. En un próximo comentario dime qué programa usas para tu programa PHP, quizá puede indicarte cómo revisar el log de errores, el cual te dirá exactamente el error.

Comment: Vale, estaba mal la ruta. Ahora pone: Hubo un error: parsererror

Comment: Pon tu `addQuestions.php` en la pregunta para revisarlo. Cambia esto en la petición Ajax: `dataType: "json"`  por **`dataType: "html"`**. Parece que el PHP no devuelve un JSON.

Comment: Ahora añadiré el código PHP. Ahora pone Todo bien tras cambiar lo de dataType.

Comment: @MikelMolinuevo si pone todo bien entonces ya funciona, si tu código PHP está correcto se harán las operaciones que pidas a la base de datos. Si quieres obtener un mensaje de confirmación en tu página actual, sólo tienes que tener un div en el cual agregues la información que obtengas del servidor.

Comment: El código PHP está bien seguro, ya que lo había usado previamente. El problema es que no se inserta en la base de datos, no entiendo por qué.