# Como almacenar los datos de salida de un input para ser enviados a la base de datos?

Tags: jquery

Lo que trato de decir es que tengo un input de texto donde en ese campo pongo una palabra y esta es mostrada en pantalla, y quisiera poder usar ese dato de salida para almacenarla despues a la base de datos. 
Para comprobar que esta bien todo al momento de crear esa palabra, lo que hice fue mostrarlo por pantalla, asi para que usuario pueda almacenarla despues atraves de un boton de jquery. Como podria hacer eso???

Comment: Buenas @Lun, debes mostrar lo que hayas probado poniendo el código en la pregunta.

Comment: aaah bueno es q solo queria saber atraves de que metodo puedo usar o algo similar para almacenar mis datos de salida

Comment: Aquí mismo, bajo la etiqueta `Ajax` encontrarás varias respuestas que explican lo que quieres hacer. [Esta por ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/117159/29967). La idea es la siguiente: Tener una formulario en la página actual, escuchar algún elemento de ese formulario (por ejemplo un botón), y al hacer clic en ese botón recoger los datos del formulario y enviarlo a un archivo PHP (servidor), el cual procesará en la base de datos la información que haya recibido (valores de los inputs y otros posibles elementos). La petición Ajax recogerá la respuesta final del servidor en el `done`.

Comment: ok gracias por tu comentario